# When Powermock annotations is live the e-mail sending is fail with exception

Tags: java, email, smtp, easymock, powermock

There is an interesting case, maybe i should report it like a bug:

When i try to send without annotations, it is works like a charm, when

i added these lines:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest()
```

(Is there any experience about it? To anybody? )
Even with (PrepareForTest()) empty content, the e-mail sending will run to fail:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 192.168.51.1, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException: Can't create MailSSLSocketFactory
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2055)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
    at reignsoft.email.EmailSender.sendMail(EmailSender.java:110)
    at reignsoft.email.EmailSender.sendMail(EmailSender.java:59)
    at reignsoft.email.EmailSenderTest.testSendMail(EmailSenderTest.java:225)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't create MailSSLSocketFactory
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:333)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:236)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2019)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for SSLContext: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS10Context not a SSLContext
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.checkSuperClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.MailSSLSocketFactory.<init>(MailSSLSocketFactory.java:112)
    at com.sun.mail.util.MailSSLSocketFactory.<init>(MailSSLSocketFactory.java:94)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:326)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: So you have a test that works without PowerMock? But if you add PowerMock in, it fails? That's very odd indeed. I would say that the `@PrepareForTest` annotation is not intended to be used without providing a class for it, so perhaps there's some weirdness occurring there?

Comment: Hi, appreciate for your answer. However this is not the cause/solution. I only make it empty to be more clear the example. It is a known issue i will describe it in my answer if i will have time (today will be). The short is: mock classloader cannot load security classes, so should ignore it... Please check it out later, if you areinterested in;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue/problem.

PowerMock classloader try to load these security classes, rather than the default classloader. So the solution is to @PowerMockIgnore() these classes, this way java classloader will do the job.

Based on this thread:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/powermock/v4nreP2AnOQ

Comment: So what classes/packages should be set at @PowerMockIgnore ?

Comment: It was a long ago, and now I had no acces to this code, but if I am right and my memory is good then the **SSLContext.class** was one or the only one class which should be ignored! (but this problem is more common I think, I mean you can ignore a lot of java.* class). Please confirm if I am right and problem is solved;)!

Comment: Yes, thanks, problem was solved with @PowerMockIgnore("com.sun.mail.util.*")